# Não consigo fazer o algoritmo pedir determinada faixa de valores

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Galera, neste algoritmo, ele pede para serem digitadas 4 notas que sejam entre 0 e 10, desconsiderar a mais baixa e fazer a média das que sobraram, as somando e dividindo por 4.

Até consigo fazer a média, mas não consegui fazer com que fossem só digitadas notas de 1 até 10...

Se alguém puder ajudar! Agradeço!!!

Faça um algoritmo para calcular a média de 4 notas de 0 a 10. porém, desprezando a menor nota.

```
i=1;
menor = 9999999;
total = 0;

while(i<=4){

    var num = Number(prompt(`Digite a nota ${i} do aluno: `));
    i++;

    if(num < menor){
        menor = num;
    }

    total = total + num;

    media = (total-menor)/4;
}
alert(`A menor nota digitada foi: ${menor}`)
alert(`A media do aluno foi: ${media}`);
```

Comment: É necessário criar uma função específica para capturar a nota do aluno. Dessa forma você consegue fazer um *loop* dentro do outro. `do { num = prompt('...') } while (num > 10)`

Comment: Mas se o aluno tirar 10, 10, 10, 10 por esse método ele fica com média 7.5 .Tem certeza que é para dividir por quatro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dexter, existem várias formas de fazer isso, uma forma muito simples, é criar uma condição que continua no loop e não incrementa sua variável de controle:

```
i = 1;
menor = 9999999;
total = 0;

while(i<=4){

    var num = Number(prompt(`Digite a nota ${i} do aluno: `));

    //Valida a nota digitada, em caso de nota inválida,
    //não incrementa a variável i e retorna para o começo do loop (continue)
    if (num < 0 || num > 10) {
        continue;
    }

    i++;

    if(num < menor){
        menor = num;
    }

    total = total + num;

    media = (total-menor)/4;
}

alert(`A menor nota digitada foi: ${menor}`);
alert(`A media do aluno foi: ${media}`);
```

Seguindo a ideia do `Valdeir Psr`, você pode criar uma função que pega a nota e já valida a mesma, mantendo um loop enquanto a nota for inválida, também recomendo essa forma, pois o código fica mais organizado:

```
//Função que solicita a nota e mantem o loop caso a nota seja inválida
function validaNotaDigitada(i) {
    let num = 0;

    do {
        num = prompt(`Digite a nota ${i} do aluno: `);
    } while (num < 0 || num > 10);

    return num;
}

i = 1;
menor = 9999999;
total = 0;

while(i<=4){

    var num = validaNotaDigitada(i);

    i++;

    if(num < menor){
        menor = num;
    }

    total = total + num;

    media = (total-menor)/4;
}

alert(`A menor nota digitada foi: ${menor}`);
alert(`A media do aluno foi: ${media}`);
```

*Obs.:* Você citou que a menor nota é 0 e também 1... Então não sei qual é realmente a menor nota válida, o código que deixei de exemplo valida a menor nota como sendo 0 (zero).

Comment: Faltou o `Number` do `prompt` que fica dentro da função

Comment: Opa, verdade, enviei a nota como parâmetro para a função, muito obrigado Isac! =)

Answer (score 0):

Eu acumularia as notas e trataria isso fora do for:

```
var notas = [], media = 0, i = 1, total = 0, qte = 4;
while(i<=qte){

    var num = Number(prompt(`Digite a nota ${i} do aluno: `));

    //Valida a nota digitada, em caso de nota inválida,
    //não incrementa a variável i e retorna para o começo do loop (continue)
    //verifica se é positivo e se vai até 10.
    if (Math.sign(num) !== -1 && num <= 10) {
        notas.push(num);
          i++;
        continue;

    } else {
        num = Number(prompt(`Digite a nota ${i} do aluno entre 0-10: `));
    }
}
var menor = Math.min(...notas);

var media = notas.reduce(function(anterior, atual) {
  return anterior + atual;
}) / qte;
var media_menor = media - menor;
alert(`A menor nota digitada foi: ${menor}`);
alert(`A média do aluno foi: ${media}`)
alert(`A nota final do aluno é: ${media_menor}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode separar o que é coleta de dados e o que é processamento. No código da pergunta isso estava um pouco confuso.

Num primeiro momento o algorítimo coleta as quatro notas e guarda na array `notas` usando o método [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Depois começa o processamento identificando o menor valor com [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) usando `notas` como [parâmetro rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

Para encontrar o total das notas apliquei o método [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
//Definição de uma estrutura para os dados
var notas = [];

//coleta de dados
for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  notas.push(Number(prompt(`Digite a nota ${i} do aluno: `)));
}

//Processamento dos dados
menor = Math.min(...notas);
total = notas.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val);

media = (total - menor) / 4; // Tenho minhas dúvidas, eu dividiria por três

minhaMedia = (total - menor) / 3; //Mantive o enunciado e  criei minha média.

//Exibição dos dados processados
console.log(`A menor nota digitada foi: ${menor}`)
console.log(`A media do aluno foi: ${media}`);
console.log(`A media que gostaria de aplicar foi: ${minhaMedia }`);
```